# При внесении и вынесении никнема из mysql пугает кодировка

Tags: php, mysql, кодировка

Здравствуйте , подскажите пожалуйста , беда в том что кодировка стоит utf-8 , в базу до этого момента заносилось и выносилось всё)) сейчас вместо никнейма `--КИМ--` в базу заносится  `--К�?М--`, как исправить это можно ?

Comment: Таблица и столбец в базе данных какую кодировку используют? Как настраиваете кодировку соединения с базой данных (SET NAMES ...)? В какой кодировке страница отправки данных в базу данных?

Comment: Именно вместо большой буквы И такое

Comment: utf-8 всё, и база и кодировка, сейчас гляну поле в базе

Comment: K и M английские или русские?

Comment: varchar(255) поле в базе

Comment: Русские К и М , Просто слово на русском пишу большими буквами и выходит такая вот ересь ) КП�?Р�?ТВ .. было КПИРИТВ

Comment: если маленькими написать --ким-- то из базы берется нормально без восклицательных знаков

Comment: В базе кодировка ut8 , но русские слова отображаются как --РєРёРј-- .. на страницу выводятся нормальными русскими буквами

Comment: Так мне никто и не поможет?(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше всего использовать кодировку **utf-8** .

1) Проверьте, что стоит у вас utf-8 в кодировке страниц(ы) с которой отправляются данные и на которой отображаются:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

2) Проверьте, чтобы у вас в базе так же стояла utf8 для базы, таблицы и самого текстового поля.

[image: Так выглядит кодировка utf8 для текстового поля в таблице]

Конечно. хватило бы uft8 и только для самого текстового поля, но это не совсем правильно, на мой взгляд.

3) Проверьте, проставляете ли вы кодировку при установке соединения с таблицей:

```
"SET NAMES utf8"
```

Это должен быть первый запрос к базе. В зависимости от вашей реализации может быть как-то так (хотя не исключены и другие варианты. т.к. я не знаю, как это сделано у вас):

```
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

или

```
mysqli_query($link, "SET NAMES utf8");
```

или если вы еще не перешли с mysql, то

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

4) Если вы выводите данные после ajax-запроса на получение информации, то если сам исполняемый код js-скрипта хранится в отдельном js-файле - так же стоит проверить кодировку js файла. Должно быть utf-8.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38275/discussion-on-answer-by-stanislav-------mysql-).